# Nesting array based on level

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

```
0: {content: "Heading 1 2 3 4 5", level: 2, anchor: "heading-1-2-3-4-5", className: "testtest", fontWeight: "", …}
1: {content: "Heading 2", level: 2, anchor: "heading-2", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
2: {content: "Inner Heading", level: 2, anchor: "inner-heading", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
3: {content: "Heading Level 3", level: 3, anchor: "heading-level-3", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
4: {content: "Heading Level 3-2", level: 3, fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", noBottomSpacing: false, …}
5: {content: "Heading Level 4", level: 4, anchor: "heading-level-4", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
6: {content: "Heading Level 2", level: 2, anchor: "heading-level-2", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
7: {content: "Heading 4", level: 6, anchor: "heading-4", fontWeight: "", textTransform: "", …}
```

I have this array in JavaScript that I need to nest based on levels.

For example,

```
level 2
level 2
level 2
   level 3
   level 3
     level 4
level 2
  level 4
```

What would be the best way to nest this?

So far, I have tried:

```
        const nestHeading = heading => {
            const nestedHeadersLength = nestedHeaders.length;

            if ( nestedHeadersLength >= 1 ) {
                const previousIndex = nestedHeadersLength - 1;

                if ( previousIndex >= 0 ) {
                    if (
                        heading.level !== nestedHeaders[ previousIndex ].level &&
                        heading.level > nestedHeaders[ previousIndex ].level
                    ) {
                        nestedHeaders[ previousIndex ].innerHeadings.push( heading );
                    } else {
                        nestedHeaders.push( heading );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                nestedHeaders.push( heading );
            }
        };
```

Heading is each item from the original dataset.

Comment: read this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set This is most popular realisation on Ruby language. Main thing is a additional lft, rgt fields thats become available all tree operations for an one query. Javascript realisation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-sets-tree

Comment: How is it relevant?

Comment: @Haris what have you tried so far please update your question?

Comment: @Ejaz47 Just did.

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected result?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic I did. I wanted an array nested based on the level key.

Comment: @Haris, your example output is little bit tricky, as you can see level 4 is coming after level 2, is this your expected output?

Comment: @Ejaz47 Yes, that is correct. Higher number (as in 1) will be on the top vs lower number (even if it's 4)

Comment: is this what you want? var arr = [
{content: "H", level: 2},
{content: "H", level: 2},
{content: "I", level: 2, next:[{content: "H3", level: 3}, {content: "H2", level: 3, next:[{content: "H4", level: 4}]}]},
{content: "2", level: 2, next:[{content: "H4", level: 6}]},
]

Comment: @Haris, [here](http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a helper array for the levels and one for the indices of each level as adjustment for not zero based or missing levels.

> Imagine, all of your `level` properties are running from zero and are build upon this value and have no holes, you could take only the line
>
> ```
> levels[index].push({ ...o, children: levels[index + 1] = [] });
> //     ^^^^^                                                      parent
> //                                          ^^^^^^^^^             children
> ```
>
> with `o.level` instead of `index`.
>
> Then only `levels` is uesd to move a node to the right position of the tree. Each level depends on the (smaller) level before.
>
> The main problem with levels not starting with zero and by having missing levels is to adjust the level to a meaningful index. This is archived by using the level as value and using the index of an array of these values. The rule of getting an index is, if not found, take the last lenght of the array and push the level to the `indices` array. Otherwise short the `indices` array to `length` of `index` plus one, to prevent deeper nested symbols to be found in the array.

```js
var data = [{ content: "Heading 1 2 3 4 5", level: 2 }, { content: "Heading 2", level: 2 }, { content: "Inner Heading", level: 2 }, { content: "Heading Level 3", level: 3 }, { content: "Heading Level 3-2", level: 3 }, { content: "Heading Level 4", level: 4 }, { content: "Heading Level 2", level: 2 }, { content: "Heading 4", level: 6 },  { content: "Heading 1", level: 1 }, { content: "Heading 5", level: 5 }],
    result = [],
    indices = [],
    levels = [result];
   
data.forEach(o => {
    var index = indices.findIndex(level => level >= o.level);
    if (index === -1) {
        index = indices.push(o.level) - 1;
    } else {
        indices.length = index + 1;
    }
    levels[index].push(Object.assign({}, o, { children: levels[index + 1] = [] }));
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is it possible for you to explain the solution line by line so that I just don't copy/paste the solution?

Comment: Thank you for explanation and that make sense.

Comment: However, if you add add another two entries to the dataset, the whole logic fails e.g.
{ content: "Heading 1", level: 1 }, { content: "Heading 5", level: 5 }

Comment: it needs the same first level `2`. otherwise it is treated as extension of the last most nested level. is it a new rule?