# Flat array table of content to nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, tableofcontents

I have an array of headings, each with their respective depth level. I'm trying to change the structure of that array so that headings contain their children.

There are similar questions and answers about making a nested array out of a flat array, but in my situation the items don't know what their parent are. Their position in the array holds this information.

Here is my non-functional attempt but I suspect it won't take much to get it working:

```js
const headings = [
  {depth: 1, value: 'I'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'I.1'},
  {depth: 3, value: 'I.1.a'},
  {depth: 3, value: 'I.1.b'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'I.2'},
  {depth: 1, value: 'II'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'II.1'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'II.2'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'II.3'},
  {depth: 3, value: 'II.3.a'},
  {depth: 3, value: 'II.3.b'},
  {depth: 2, value: 'II.4'},
  {depth: 1, value: 'III'},
  {depth: 1, value: 'IV'},
];

const result = [
  {depth: 1, title: 'I', headings: [
    {depth: 2, title: 'I.1', headings: [
      {depth: 3, title: 'I.1.a'},
      {depth: 3, title: 'I.1.b'},
    ]},
    {depth: 2, title: 'I.2'},
  ]},
  {depth: 1, title: 'II', headings: [
    {depth: 2, title: 'II.1'},
    {depth: 2, title: 'II.2'},
    {depth: 2, title: 'II.3', headings: [
      {depth: 3, title: 'II.3.a'},
      {depth: 3, title: 'II.3.b'},
    ]},
    {depth: 2, title: 'II.4'},
  ]},
  {depth: 1, title: 'III'},
  {depth: 1, title: 'IV'},
];

const parse = (values = [], carriage = true) => {
  if (values.length) {
    const [ { depth, value } = {}, next = {}, ...rest ] = values;
    if (depth !== undefined && carriage) {
      return [{
        depth,
        headings: next.depth > depth ? parse([next, ...rest]) : [],
        value,
      }, ...(next.depth < depth ? [] : parse([next, ...rest], next.depth === depth))];
    }
    else if (depth !== undefined) {
      return parse([next, ...rest], next.depth < depth);
    }
  }
  return [];
};

console.log(parse(headings));
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8c7nse9w/  Just because the question closed before I could post an answer.

Comment: @Taplar, that is not really shorter than the duplicate target ...

Comment: @NinaScholz shorter is not always better.

Comment: @Taplar: No, of course not.  But if you compare it to the answer from Nenad or Nina's answer to the duplicate question, it's quite clear that those are simpler.  And simpler is almost always better.

Comment: @NinaScholz The duplicate target assumes depth starts at 0.

Comment: for your actuall data set, you could just subtract one and get a zero based level. if you have holes in the levels, you could take this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59487521/nesting-array-based-on-level/59488534#59488534

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes there may be holes, thanks for the link that looks like what I'm after indeed.